# Exporting a PFX file for Smartcard authentication driver issues

Tags: windows, certificate, smartcard

I have a ACR122 Smartcard reader I am attempting to export a PFX certificate to for password-less authentication. I have everything set up on the active directory server, but am stuck on the simplest and most frustrating issue: the driver for the actual smart card. I've tried searching the internet, using terms like, "ntag215 driver", "ntag215 driver for Windows", etc. I even tried to create my own filter driver to no avail.

The hardware ID is `SCFILTER\CID_804f0ca00000030603000000000000`.

When I try to run...
`certutil -csp "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider" -importpfx id.pfx`
...then I get an error...
`The smart card requires drivers that are not present on this system. Please try another smart card or contact your Administrator.`

Does anyone know how to obtain the appropriate driver for this card? I was able to ascertain the card's information using an Android app, but Windows will barely recognize the card. Also, I have installed all of the drivers for the reader.

Comment: Did you try to search in smart card's vendor website?

Comment: I tried that - they were purchased from eBay. Unfortunately, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may download these from Microsoft Catalog web site:

https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=ACR122%20Smartcard%20reader%20

[image: Catalog web site]

[image: Catalog web site download description]

[image: Catalog web site 3]

[image: Catalog web site download cab file contents]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already have the latest drivers for the reader, that doesn't appear to be the problem. The issue is the driver for the NFC card _itself_, which the PC is unable to recognize as a smart card, and instead uses Microsoft's "Universal Smart Card" driver for. It may need a custom driver, but I'm hoping someone out there has already done this? The card is recognized on NFC Tools on both Windows and Android as a "ntag215" model smart card, and is able to interact with it. My hope is that there is a way to program these smart cards using certutil so that I may use them.